# Why is this code giving me out of bound error?

Tags: java, recursion, dynamic-programming

```
public static int helper(int r, int c, int[][] dp) {
    if (r == 1 || c == 1)
        return dp[r][c] = 1;
    if (dp[r][c] == 0) {
        dp[r][c] = helper(r - 1, c, dp) + helper(r, c - 1, dp);
    }
    return dp[r][c];
}

public static int count(int r, int c) {
    int dp[][] = new int[r][c];
    for(int i =0; i<r ;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<c;j++){
            dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    int ans = helper(r, c, dp);
    return ans;
}
```

when i didnt use the helper function it worked fine but doing like this it gives an error -
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

//updated
public class maze {

```
public static int count(int r, int c, int[][] dp) {
    if (r == 1 || c == 1)
        return dp[r][c] = 1;
    if (dp[r][c] == 0) {
        dp[r][c] = count(r - 1, c, dp) + count(r, c - 1, dp);
    }
    return dp[r][c];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int dp[][] = new int[4][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < dp.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dp.length; j++) {
            dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count(1, 1, dp));
    System.out.println(count(2, 3, dp));
    System.out.println(count(3, 2, dp));
    System.out.println(count(3, 3, dp));
    // System.out.println(count(18, 18, dp));

}
```

}

//this code will now work except for the larger input i.e (18 , 18)

Comment: You exceeded the bounds of the array. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Also, include complete, minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: Java array indexes are zero based.

Comment: actually this was a dp question (grid traveller). Please see now , i have updated the question for more clarification.This code works if don't use the helper method to create the memoized array but when i create using another method it throws that out of bound error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following condition should have a check that your r - 1 or c- 1 does not go below 0

```
    if (dp[r][c] == 0) {
        dp[r][c] = helper(r - 1, c, dp) + helper(r, c - 1, dp);
    }
```

Also when calling helper from count reduce the values by 1 so that it points to last index and not outside as pointed out by @hfontanez

Comment: Did you even run the code? The code fails because whichever values you pass for `r` and `c` are used to determine the size of the array and also to start iterating.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Ran with the following
```public static int helper(int r, int c, int[][] dp) {
    if (r == 1 || c == 1)
        return dp[r][c] = 1;
    if (dp[r][c] == 0 && r - 1 > 0 && c - 1 > 0) {
        dp[r][c] = helper(r - 1, c, dp) + helper(r, c - 1, dp);
    }
    return dp[r][c];
}

public static int count(int r, int c) {
    int dp[][] = new int[r][c];
    for(int i =0; i<r ;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<c;j++){
            dp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    int ans = helper(r - 1, c - 1, dp);
    return ans;
}```

Comment: That prevents the error, but does not fix the algorithm. That code is beyond help. The OP never made clear what he or she was trying to do.

Comment: I think the question was to answer the problem related to out of bound exception. He did not explained or asked to fix the algorithm

Comment: I know that. My comment was about the quality of the OP''s question